# displaying variable from php file

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a discount code for shopping cart that calculates a deduction of %10, all works fine, but I'd like to display the amount that has been discounted (`$discount_amount`) as a minus value (-£2.50) or display £0.00 if no discount has been applied, just not sure how the best way to go about it is, any advice much appreciated.

page.php:

```
$currency = '£';

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "coupon_dis")
{
    $couponcode = trim($_POST['couponval']);
    $amnt = $_POST['amnt'];
    $val = '0';
    if($couponcode == "loyalty10"){
        $couponDiscount_val = "10";
        $discount_amount = ($amnt*$couponDiscount_val)/100;
        $amount_after_discount = $amnt - $discount_amount;
        $val = sprintf("%01.2f", $amount_after_discount);
    }
    $_SESSION['discount_amount'] = sprintf("%01.2f", $discount_amount);
    $_SESSION['product_discount'] = $val;
    echo $currency.$val;
}
```

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addcoupon").click(function(){
    var ttlamt = $("#ttl_amount").val();
    var ccode = $("#couponcode").val();
    var cpn = ccode.replace(/\s/g, '');
    if(cpn.length <= 0){
        $("#couponcode").css("border-color","red");
    }else{
      $("#couponcode").css("border-color","");
      $.ajax({
          url: "page.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {action:"coupon_dis",couponval: cpn,amnt: ttlamt},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            if(data != "0"){
                $("#grandamount").css("display","none");
                $("#couponcode").css("border-color","green");
                $("#grand_discount_amount").css("display","block");
                $("#grand_discount_amount").html(data);
            }else{
              $("#grandamount").css("text-decoration","");
              $("#couponcode").css("border-color","");
              $("#grand_discount_amount").html("");
              $("#grand_discount_amount").css("display","none");
            }
          }
      });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return more than a single value from your PHP:

```
// ... your code

$return = [
    'price' => $currency.$val
    'discount' => $currency.$discount_amount
];

// Make sure Javascript knows you're returning JSON data
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Now you can use those values in your Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
      // Specify that the response will be JSON
      dataType: 'json',

      // ... your code

      success: function(data){
          // Now you can access each element of your response with dot notation
          $("#grand_discount_amount").html(data.discount);
          $("#some_other_field").html(data.price);
```

Answer (score 0):

gmp_neg("$var") should do the part of converting value to negative. But that change positive to negative and negative to positive. Can't you just multiply $discount_amount with (-1)? 0*(-1)=0...
If you want to display it on same page, can use ajax(you used), but if you want to split the result of php in more arrays, you can use json_encode_array. Or you can stock what you need in $_SESSION...